# Text decoration color linear gradient

Tags: html, css

please how do I set a linear-gradient to a text-decoration-color property in css. I've been trying to implement it but it's not working

> `[what I actually wanted it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDKhi.jpg)`

Comment: What did you already try and where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't see that the image you have given contains text that is colored, is it the underline that you want to be a linear gradient rather than the actual characters? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you put the code you have tried so far into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linear-gradient custom underline to a text with line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68501697/linear-gradient-custom-underline-to-a-text-with-line-break)

Answer (score 4):

```css
p{
 background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,rgb(98,60,49)0,rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position-y: bottom;
 background-size:100% 15%;
 width:fit-content;
}
```

```html
<p>This is text with a gradient decoration</p>
```

Something like this could work. Backgrounds should be your friend in this situation.

Comment: The best solution so far , work for different font-sizes , its responsive . 

Answer (score 0):

The best way (in my opinion) is a `::before` or just a `div` to do the same effect. Ex:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
}

p::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(111.3deg, #9c27b0 9.6%, #00bcd4 93.6%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>I love CSS</p>
</div>
```

[Reference](https://www.amitmerchant.com/gradient-text-underlines-using-css/)

Comment: Could you explain why this is 'best'. Altering the DOM just for a visual effect is not normally a great idea. I can understand the pseudo element, but the background solution given already seems quite neat.

Comment: Sorry about that @AHaworth

Comment: I think it is, because you can add a css in that element to see a great effect. For example: border-radius, transform, and sometimes box-shadow.

Comment: Being stuck only in the element itself, I think it is limited (background-image is a ex)

Comment: Thanks, yes it is more limited for a more general situation.